# How to manipulate with style of vector image in SVG format?

Tags: wpf, xaml, svg

I have got button Lock and button Unlock placed together in my app. The problem is that they have vector SVG images as content, both are black, so it seems that both buttons are enabled, so I need to change the color on gray, if it's unabled.

Assigning image as button content is realized like this:

```
<Button x:Name="LockButton" Content="{StaticResource LockButton}"/>
```

So lock image is some style:

```
<Rectangle x:Key="LockButton" Style="{StaticResource ButtonRectangle}">
    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Canvas Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
                    <Path Width="34.8333" Height="41.1667" Canvas.Left="20.5833" Canvas.Top="17.4167" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="M 12 0 C 8.699219 0 6 2.699219 6 6 L 6 11 L 3 11 L 3 24 L 21 24 L 21 11 L 18 11 L 18 6 C 18 2.699219 15.300781 0 12 0 Z M 12 2 C 14.21875 2 16 3.78125 16 6 L 16 11 L 8 11 L 8 6 C 8 3.78125 9.78125 2 12 2 Z"/>                      
                </Canvas>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

And for this Rectangle there is another style:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonRectangle" TargetType="Rectangle">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
</Style>
```

So I think, that I need to make DataTrigger for some of these blocks. But I don't know how to bind IsEnabled property of button in inner styles. Another idea is to make the same rectangle style with gray fill and make DataTrigger, which will apply different styles to button, depending on value of IsEnabled property.

So, what do you think, how would you solve this?

Comment: Why do you have the rectangle, canvas and opacity mask rather than just a path?

Comment: @Andy Probably generated by some SVG to XAML conversion tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't put visual elements (Rectangle) in Resources - it makes difficult to modify and use them. instead define VisualBrush as resource, apply OpacityMask in Rectangle Style, add DataTrigger in RectangleStyle, and then use rectangle with that Style as Button.Content:

```
<VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" x:Key="LockButtonIco">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Canvas Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
            <Path Width="34.8333" Height="41.1667" Canvas.Left="20.5833" Canvas.Top="17.4167" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="M 12 0 C 8.699219 0 6 2.699219 6 6 L 6 11 L 3 11 L 3 24 L 21 24 L 21 11 L 18 11 L 18 6 C 18 2.699219 15.300781 0 12 0 Z M 12 2 C 14.21875 2 16 3.78125 16 6 L 16 11 L 8 11 L 8 6 C 8 3.78125 9.78125 2 12 2 Z"/>                      
        </Canvas>
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>

<Style x:Key="ButtonRectangle" TargetType="Rectangle">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />

    <Setter Property="OpacityMask" Value="{StaticResource LockButtonIco}" />

    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
        </DataTrigger>
    <Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Button x:Name="LockButton">
    <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource ButtonRectangle}"/>
</Button>
```

or maybe apply OpacityMask to each Rectangle, not in style:

```
<Button x:Name="LockButton">
    <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource ButtonRectangle}"
               OpacityMask="{StaticResource LockButtonIco}"/>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Better use the Path as Content of a Button and bind its `Fill` property to the Button's `Foreground`.

```
<Geometry x:Key="LockGeometry">M 12 0 C 8.699219 0 6 2.699219 6 6 L 6 11 L 3 11 L 3 24 L 21 24 L 21 11 L 18 11 L 18 6 C 18 2.699219 15.300781 0 12 0 Z M 12 2 C 14.21875 2 16 3.78125 16 6 L 16 11 L 8 11 L 8 6 C 8 3.78125 9.78125 2 12 2 Z</Geometry>
...

<Button Style="{StaticResource IconButtonStyle}">
    <Path Data="{StaticResource LockGeometry}"
          Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"
          Width="16" Height="16" Margin="4" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Button>
```

The Foreground would be set by a Style like:

```
<Style x:Key="IconButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```